# Mouse hover CSS Position absolute div display on another TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using HTML table. My goal simple. I am trying to make a menu when mouse hover open div open. But in this implement in table.

When I mouse hover on `<span>Telephone:</span>` element as soon as below element `<div class="secondary_menu">...</div>` visible on right side **`<td>`** element (using z-index) as **position `absolute`**.

View [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GchWZ/212/)

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Telephone:<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></span>
      <div class="secondary_menu">
        <ul>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using CSS, jquery.

[image]

Comment: Please rephrase the question, it is not clear enough what you're asking.

Comment: Hey @l0lander why you not understand. I was writre clearly, still I highlight word that are important. Thanks

Comment: The image itself is unclear.

Comment: Hello, @LekzFlores
`div` element exist in first `<td>` as display none. But When the mouse hovers on the telephone `div` element visible on rightside `td` at top up layer (I think we here use position absolute and z-index). But I am not archive this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in CSS alone using the `:hover` and sibling selectors:

```css
table span:hover + .secondary_menu {
    display: block;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GchWZ/216/)

Comment: please read what i am saying when mouse hover  `secondary_menu` element will visible in beside on `td` element in `absolute` position.

Answer (score 3):

check this below code as per you requested for demo

```js
$(".maincontent").hover(function() {
    $('.secondary_menu').addClass(".active");
}, function() {
    $('.secondary_menu').removeClass(".active");
});
```

```css
table,
tr td:last-child {
  position: relative;
}
td > div {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
tr:hover td > div {
  opacity: 1;
}
tbody tr td:first-child:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 0.5s;
}
tbody tr:hover td:first-child:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
td > div > a {
  
  background: #1DE9B6;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
  margin-left : 10px;
}
/*Not important -- example only*/

td > div > a:hover {
  background: #A7FFEB;
  color: #000;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #EEE;
}
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #EEE;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #E3F2FD;
}

table  tr  td {
  width : 50%;
}

.secondary_menu li{
  width : 300px;
  list-style-type : none;
}

.secondary_menu{
  display : none;
  width : 70px;
}

.maincontent:hover .secondary_menu {
  display : block !important;
  width : 70px;
}

.maincontent{
  padding : 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active{display : block !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="maincontent">Telephone:
          <ul class="secondary_menu">
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
        </ul></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div><a href="#">989898989898</a><a href="#">989898989898</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="maincontent">Telephone:
          <ul class="secondary_menu">
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
        </ul></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div><a href="#">989898989898</a><a href="#">989898989898</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: When mouse hovers `secondary_menu` element will visibly, but the position is `absolute` and display on rightside `TD` element in top layer.

Comment: Hello @Iqbal Pasha 
When hover on Telephone you div will display inside in right side `<td>` element (here i think use position absolute, ans z-index properties).

Comment: Here you can give on hover display none/block not z-index

Comment: yes i use display properties but can you show me demo.

Comment: @S͢ky D͢ream check updated code which is per you need.

Comment: Hello @Iqbal Pasha 
`My Dashboard` div visible on rightside `TD` element area. Anyway, here we can use z-index and position absolute to achieve this ?

Comment: hi @S͢ky D͢ream i dint get your point can u please explain it?

Comment: `Div` element ( have some list `My Dashboard` content), exist in left size `<td>` element as display none. Assume this `<td>` width is only 10% so obviously when mouse hover, `<div>` element overlap and visible on right side `<td>` element area. 

So my goal is when mouse, `<div>` element visible on right side`<td>` element. No matter here allow to use z-index, possition absolute. Thank you Iqbal Pasha

Comment: why don't you keep Dashboard in right side of table <td> instead of keeping in left <td>

Comment: Because in my case left `td` use for menu and sub menu. when left `td` collapse. And mouse hover on menu as soon as sub menu visible on right side `<td>`. that i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sibling selector to change the `display` of the `secondary_menu` when the span is hover

```
span:hover+.secondary_menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/GchWZ/214/

Comment: When mouse hovers `secondary_menu` element will visibly, but the position is `absolute` and display on rightside `TD` element in top layer.